# Fade In/Out of DIV and nested DIV's

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get a scenario working to where I can fade a div in and out, replacing it with a another div. This part I've got working, but my DIV completely disappears if the DIV I fade into has DIV's within it.

Example:

```
<center>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#content1">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|</li>
            <li><a href="#content2">Work</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|</li>
            <li><a href="#content3">Blog</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|</li>
            <li><a href="#content4">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </center>
        <hr class="style-main">
        <center><img src="{image:homeHeaderImage}"></center>
</div>

 <div id="contentWrap">
   <div id="content1">
         Home, content should go here :)

     </div>
```

This works, If the contents of DIV "content1" look like this it'll perfectly fade in and out.
But, since I want to style the contents of "content1" and "content2" etc, I've placed DIVs inside like so.

```
<div id="contentWrap">
   <div id="content1">
         <div id="homeContent">
         Home, content should go here :(
         </div>

     </div>
```

This makes it so when I click on the link to fade this particular DIV in turn it completely white with no content. I cannot figure out why it will not render the content.

I'm using this for my jQuery script

```
$(function() {
$('#contentWrap div').hide();
$('#contentWrap div:first').show();
$('#thumbs a:first').addClass('active');

$('#thumbs a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') == true) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $('a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $('#contentWrap div').fadeOut();
        var contentToLoad = $(this).attr('href');
        $(contentToLoad).fadeIn();

        return false;
    }
});
```

});

Here's a jsFiddle, the Home menu item is the one which has the problem. The other ones work fine as you can tell.

http://jsfiddle.net/uyAzp/

Comment: You should probably set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show the problem.

Comment: Added the jsFiddle, maybe that'll help.

Comment: i corrected your jsfiddle it was bad setupped http://jsfiddle.net/uyAzp/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS selectors are set to select ALL `div` elements under `#contentWrap`.

If you change them to `#contentWrap > div` this will only select those that are direct children.

Like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uyAzp/4/)

To avoid them all displaying at the same time on load, you should add `display: none` to the CSS for `#contentWrap > div`

Comment: Now this works perfectly just by replacing the snippet I was using. Thank you so much, I've been pulling my hair out trying to fix this.

Comment: Do you know why it wouldn't work on local machine. Copied code straight from jsFiddle and it doesn't work on my Mac. This is the answer though. NVM, Got it, thanks again man.

Comment: when I copied it over I left out a > in the css and it took me a bit to realize it.

Answer (score 3):

in your jQuery you have this line:

```
$('#contentWrap div').hide();
```

This causes all divs to hide, including the div inside #content1

so when you click the home button, #content1 does fade it, but the div inside #content1 containing the info you want to show is still hidden.

You could easily solve it by adding this to your css:

```
#homeContent{ display:block !important; }
```

Although it might be better to slightly rewrite your jQuery so you don't have to hide all those divs to begin with. ( put them on display:none through your css )

Comment: Tried adding that to the CSS but doesn't seem to show content of the nest DIV's still. Hmm, well that's odd. Updated the css in the jsFiddle and it works there but on my machines it won't display it. Thanks for the answer. This will work.

Comment: Says I need 15 Rep to upvote your answer. If I create any more divs inside of that div will I have to add the display: block !import; css tag to it as well?

Comment: what I would do is give a class to all the divs you want to hide, and use that class to target all those divs in your jQuery or css.

Answer (score 0):

**Just update this line :**

```
$('#contentWrap div:first').show();
```

**with this:**

```
$('#contentWrap div:first-child').show();
```

see if this helps.

Comment: This makes it display all four divs at one time, when I click on the others and come back to the home div it remains white.